# Bigquery Python API create partitioned table by specific field

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to create a table in Bigquery partitioned by a specific field. I have noticed that this is only available via API Rest. Is there a way to do this via Python API?

Any help?

Comment: Use a [CREATE TABLE statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#create_table_statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the docs just haven't been updated yet (not that rolling a http request and calling the API would be hard anyway), because if you look at the [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/dd330d6da892417a7701c817d7baee63a19e9883/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py#L1165) for the BigQuery Python client library, it does indeed appear to support specifying the field when creating a partitioned table:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Graham Polley's answer: You can set this by setting the `time_partitioning` property.

Something like this:

```py
import google.cloud.bigquery as bq
bq_client = bq.Client()
dataset = bq_client.dataset('dataset_name')
table = dataset.table('table_name')
table = bq.Table(table, schema=[
  bq.SchemaField('timestamp', 'TIMESTAMP', 'REQUIRED'),
  bq.SchemaField('col_name', 'STRING', 'REQUIRED')])

table.time_partitioning = bq.TimePartitioning(field='timestamp')

bq_client.create_table(table)
```